# managing disk using fdisk utility

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, fedora, fdisk

i m new to fedora, I want to create 8GB disk and then want to make three partitions with different sizes.

-first partition with 8MB

-Second partition with 192MB

-Third partition with 7.8GB

but it showing disk size only 192KB. I know that qcow2 image expands as data is inserted into it upto its maximum size. but i want to create above mentioned partition layout. please help me to so .... !!

```
[root@localhost zzz]# qemu-img create -f qcow2 guest.qcow2 8G
Formatting 'guest.qcow2', fmt=qcow2 size=8589934592 encryption=off cluster_size=65536 lazy_refcounts=off 

[root@localhost zzz]# fdisk guest.qcow2
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.25.2).

Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Device does not contain a recognized partition table.

Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0xa70e1cb5.

Command (m for help): n

Partition type

   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)

   e   extended (container for logical partitions)

Select (default p): p

Partition number (1-4, default 1): 

First sector (1-384, default 1): 

Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G,T,P} (1-384, default 384): 


Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux' and of size 192 KiB.


Command (m for help):
```

Comment: Fdisk operates on a disk, not on a disk image. You need to mount your qcow2 image as a block device.